# Using HtmlMediaElement.captureStream() to get the audio from a video

Tags: javascript, video, mediaelement

I'm trying to capture the audio track from a video and play it separately.  I wrote the test page shown below.  I'm able to capture the stream and I get a valid audio track with readyState == "live", but I hear nothing.  What am I doing wrong?

The video I'm using comes from here: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4.  I'm serving the HTML and the video locally to avoid CORS issues.

```
<head>
<script>
function captureAudio() {
 const videoEl = document.getElementById("video")
 videoEl.volume = 0.0
 
 const videoStream = videoEl.captureStream()
 const audioTrack = videoStream.getAudioTracks()[0]

 const audioStream = new MediaStream()
 audioStream.addTrack(audioTrack)

 const audioEl = document.createElement("audio")
 audioEl.srcObject = audioStream
 audioEl.autostart = true
 audioEl.volume = 1.0
 audioEl.muted = false
}
</script>
<body>
<video id="video" src="http://localhost:3000/BigBuckBunny.mp4" controls onplay="captureAudio()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a bug, caused by https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=764133#c17 I left a comment there to let them know about it. What is your exact use case? DO you use that video only to capture the audio from it? In that case, AudioContext.decodeAudioData might be an alternative.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for the info.  I do need to show the video.  My use case is a workaround for another chromium issue,  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=687574.  To get echo cancellation for a video I capture the audio and pipe it through a local WebRTC loop.  This works fine when I'm using Shaka Player or hls.js, but I'm looking for a solution when using a plain video element.

Comment: I'm not sue to completely follow... You are trying to get the AEC working on a media read from a <video>? I can get you a WebRTC looped stream from that <video> element while having the original <video> element not make a sound https://jsfiddle.net/jqdarhnk/, but I don't think you'll be able to apply echoCancelation on this track, it seems they do accept it only for gUM captured tracks.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you set a volume different than `0` (for example, `0.5`). I have modified your code and hosted it [on Glitch](https://safe-innovative-spy.glitch.me/). When you pause the `audio` (that I have attached to the DOM so you can interact with it), you can clearly hear the different sources of sound, one from the `video` and one from the `audio`.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function captureAudio() {
        const videoEl = document.getElementById("video");
        videoEl.volume = 0.5;

        const videoStream = videoEl.captureStream();
        const audioTrack = videoStream.getAudioTracks()[0];

        const audioStream = new MediaStream();
        audioStream.addTrack(audioTrack);

        const audioEl = document.createElement("audio");
        audioEl.controls = true;
        document.body.append(audioEl);
        audioEl.srcObject = audioStream;
        audioEl.play();
        audioEl.volume = 1.0;
        audioEl.muted = false;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video
      id="video"
      crossorigin
      src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
      controls
      onplay="captureAudio()"
    />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So how would I replace the video's audio track with my captured and processed one?  Is there some way to disable the video element's sound that isn't setting volume = 0 or muted = true?

Comment: Probably [WebCodecs](https://web.dev/webcodecs/) can get you there, but I am not an expert in this.